# Error message when running npm in WebStorm - Windows_NT 10.0.14393

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, webstorm

I'm running npm in WebStorm on Windows 10 Home Edition. The project is checked out from GitHub. WebStorm is run as administrator, the modules has full access control.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Sara\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Sara\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "unit"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! monitoring-web@1.0.0 unit: `karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the monitoring-web@1.0.0 unit script 'karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the monitoring-web package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs monitoring-web
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls monitoring-web
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Project\monitoring-web\npm-debug.log
```

I can't understand why I receive this error message. I appreciate your help.

Comment: the message doesn't include any useful info. it just indicates that karma has failed for some reason. Please open the command prompt, cd to your project folder and then run `karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run` there - what is the result?

Comment: Thanks, I did it, seemingly it doesn't recognize karma. I got this message : D:\Project\monitoring-web>karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run
'karma' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I'm using the webstorm terminal to run the command

Comment: do you have karma installed?

Comment: yes, version 1.4.0 is installed

Comment: Thanks for the karma hint! Actually the unit test were not running at that time and as you said it was not including any useful info. I configured the karma in webstorm and it was discovered that it cant find the test files. this problem was solved by adding .spec at the end of the file name. The test can be run now but there errors are still persisting